# Oculus Go with Unity: You can attach debugger now

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I have connected Oculus Go via USB to PC and started Build and run in Unity 2018.2.10f1. My app is not started but I see white board where one eye can see "You can attach mana" and the second eye "ugger if you want". There is an OK button. I cannot proceed because there is no way to press the button. Oculus trigger is not available in this screen. Any idea how to skip this dialog?

Update: this happens whenever I start the app now. Even manually from Unknown sources and having USB disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

That was stupid mistake. I had turned on Wait on a managed debugger. Turning it off made me start the game.

[image]